# Ubuntu graphics Intel and nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I use 18.04 LTS version of Ubuntu. My laptop is Acer travelmate. And there is Intel and Nvidia graphics card. When I'm going to `settings-details`, it shows me graphics - intel. ALWAYS. But when I'm going to nvidia-settings-PRIME profiles. It shows me graphics - nvidia.
And it show me only intel graphics when in terminal I enter this 
`lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"`
What is this and how to fix it? I want to choose nvidia. And I've already installed drivers from Additional drivers ta, driver-390.
Now try to chose intel and then again nvidia, so i ended up loosing all resolutions except some of well 940 and so on. HELP!

Comment: I guess you didn't even try to look around for the issue that you're facing, right?

Comment: wrong. I try and all that i find was for 16.04 and more old versions, also all that i find was "that is secure boot. It dose not work with nvidia". Yeah. Great. And nothing else. So question still open.

Comment: I already gave a detailed answer to your query

Comment: Thanks for the interest. 
i try it already but i do it again. And miracle dose not happen. 
Still settings-details show me Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
also i can say that with command `sudo lshw -class display` i can see my 2 displays intel and nvidia. And nvidia has *-display UNLCAIMED. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes I do have an answer for that too. I'm going to edit the main answer to include that

Comment: It would be nice. And if it solve the issue then even more nice!

Answer (score -1):

It's not an error or problem that you're facing in here. It's simply you're confused with the output that you're shown in here. With the following command you can have the complete view of your system.

```
inxi -Fv
```

In the output of the above command you would be able to see every detail of your system including your graphics drivers. 
In most of the new computers it comes with two graphics cards, one is an integrated one (Intel) and the other is a dedicated one (AMD or Nvidia).  According to the memory usage the system can switch between them automatically but that only happens in Windows. In Linux you can go and type the following in the terminal

```
  sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

and look for the recommended one and install that using

```
  sudo apt install nvidia-xxx (replace those xxx with the version name)
```

after this reboot your system and from `nvidia-settings` go to PRIME profile and select the Nvidia card. I guess this would solve your query to the fullest.

Now look at the output of `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` only one of the graphics card is getting recognized for **VGA** because it is VGA compatible and the other (Nvidia) which is not. So it basically means when you add a second display unit only the VGA compatible GPU would be in use.

`display UNCLAIMED` means that there's only one display unit connected to it. So unless you think of adding another monitor to it don't bother.

I'm providing you with the link even

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1327142

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/%5Bsolved%5D-display-unclaimed-can%27t-change-resolution-4175624346/

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/intel-graphics-lshw-display-unclaimed-4175550488/

Comment: alright.. so... can i even swap them? I mean intel to nvidia. i enter this command and get only 1 red VGA. 00:02 intel. 
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
 Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
 Kernel driver in use: i915`
And where my resolutions are gone? I start with 1920x1080 and now have only 2 with 960x540 and 864x486. And why i can switch to nvidia in PRIME profiles then? oO 
Well, let`s start from top with: how can i use nvidia graphics instead of intel and how if i can?

Comment: I guess I already provided the answer to that

Comment: so i cant? i am not ask just for spent some time. and i didn`t see some of "yes u can swap. For that u need to do this and that" or "no u cant" or something.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not willing to spoon feed you at every step. I already provided you with the basic answer. Now you have to do your own research. And now if you face any problem then post it

Comment: Man, i already 6 hours in "research". And research for why the heck in settings i have intel graphics and in nvidia settings i have nvidia graphics. My question is simple as cake - can i use nvidia graphics card in ubuntu and if yes so how? 
Why the heck i install ubuntu and have normal resolution, but then suddenly it switched to low res just cos i use nvidia settings to change graphics. i`m really tired and post this not for some of riddle "find answer yourself my young padawan." And so i asked - can it be fixed? And if YES so How?

Comment: and this question not about drivers cos they are installed from the very start. This question about bug or what is that, why ubuntu cant use nvidia card and display it correctly. Jeez.

Comment: Bugs are off topic here.

Comment: @Tintin Honestly, moves like yours just suck. You obviously have the answer to this rather obscure problem, but instead of providing them, like a normal human being, you insist on "not spoon feeding". People like you are the reason the Linux community has such a terrible reputation.